# Trelliscope: Error in cog_desc(count_names[1], "minimum group count name") : Assertion on 'x' failed: Must be of type 'atomic scalar', not 'NULL'

Tags: r, facet-wrap

Whenever I run my code I get this error,

Error in cog_desc(count_names[1], "minimum group count name") :
Assertion on 'x' failed: Must be of type 'atomic scalar', not 'NULL'.

would anyone have an idea what I may need to do with my data. The data also has some NAs Time and overall are both numeric variables while id is a character variable.

```
    qplot(Time, overall, data =pur_longdata) +
      facet_trelliscope(~ distinct_id) +
       theme_bw()
```

Comment: Did you ever find out what caused this? I'm seeing the same error message

Answer (score 0):

A potential cause is that the X feature is not in numeric format but is likely a character.

`Assertion on 'x' failed: Must be of type 'atomic scalar.'`

It is screaming that the x feature is not in numeric format. Quick fix:

`pur_longdata <- pur_longdata %>% mutate(Time = as.numeric(Time))`

I can't reproduce the example because no access to pur_longdata was given. However, this solution may aid someone with a similar error.